# Having SerializationException when trying to return custom object type

Tags: java, serialization, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I just create the most simple Singleton EJB to return a custom serializable object, but I'm getting the following exception when I invoke the remote method:

org.jboss.serial.exception.SerializationException: Could not create instance of model.Usuario - model.Usuario

It works fine with simple types and normal classes (String for example) but not for an object pertaining to a class I created.

I'm using JBoss 6.0 and Eclipse.

What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance,
Saul

Comment: code & full stacktrace please

Comment: Does Usuario implement Serializable?

Answer (score 2):

1.You should make your Object implementing [`Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

2.Have all nonserializable fields marked as `transient`.

Comment: I just arrived at home now and tested the code again and it works. Oh, I really can't imagine what was wrong, I didn't chance anything. Maybe the problem was with JBoss and after rebooting something changed and the problem was gone. Anyway, really thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

The class you are trying to serialize must implement the `Serializable` marker interface or extend a class that implements it. Also, every non-transient member of your class must also be `Serializable`.

Comment: I just arrived at home now and tested the code again and it works. Oh, I really can't imagine what was wrong, I didn't chance anything. Maybe the problem was with JBoss and after rebooting something changed and the problem was gone. Anyway, really thank you for your answers!